# [Mono][lighttpd] Accessing subdomains

Tags: mono, debian, subdomain, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm trying to set up a webserver with more than one website running on it. 
Those are `.aspx` sites.

I managed to get one site running but I'm struggling when trying to run more than one site.

This one is my latest try:

```
#lighttpd.conf



server.document-root = "/var/www"

# some other configurations like server.port...

$HTTP["host"] == "myDomain.xyz" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/myDomain"
}

fastcgi.server = (
    "" => ((
    "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi-mono-server4",
    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4",
    "bin-environment" => (
        "PATH" => "/bin:/usr/bin",
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => "/usr/lib:",
        "MONO_SHARED_DIR" => "/tmp/",
        "MONO_FCGI_LOGLEVES" => "Standard",
        "MONO_FCGI_LOGFILE" => "/tmp/fastcgi.log",
        "MONO_FCGI_ROOT" => server.document-root,
        "MONO_FCGI_APPLICATIONS" => "myDomain:/:/var/www/myDomain,/:." ),
    "max-procs" => 4,
    "check-local" => "disable"
)) )
```

I've tried all combinations for `"MONO_FCGI_APPLICATIONS"` I could think of. The result was that either all domains pointed to the same file or one file only worked.

When turning off `fastcgi` the redirects to the directories depending on the domain work fine.

How do I have to configure the server to run more than one `.aspx` site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

It's the line `"MONO_FCGI_APPLICATIONS" => "myDomain:/:/var/www/myDomain,/:."`

I changed it to

```
    "MONO_FCGI_APPLICATIONS" => "/:/var/www,myDomain:/:/var/www/myDomain"
```

I had to define which directory the empty domain (=> any) points to (= `/:/var/www`)